# Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined variable: pro_price in

Tags: magento-2.0.4, undefined-variable

Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined variable: pro_price in
/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/widget/new/content/categories_shop.phtml on line 112

i'm getting this error even if comments or remove pro_price variable.
code where i'm getting this error ,its comes after deleting most of the products from catalog. before this was working fine. any suggestion?
this small code from file

```
$type = 'widget-new-grid';
$categoryProducts = $category1->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');                             
foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
     $pro_price=$block->getProductPriceHtml($product, $type);
}
```

Comment: try to declare `$pro_price` before the foreach-loop

Comment: thanks for reply robin. i got the problem and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reply robin. i got the problem and solved it. my client deleted some virtual products ,magento 2 creates virtual products or simple product  with creation of configurable product. it store the price configurable product in virtual or simple product. so mistake was he need to delete configurable product and its virtual products too. when he deleted virtual product which carry configurable product price in it so there will be no price for that configurable product . so i got the error.